# Issue with rectify on rotated raster using R Raster

Tags: r, raster, image-rotation, r-raster

I am trying to rectify a rotated raster using the R Raster package. 
Below is the implementation with the mnf_filename being the raster file I'm trying to read.

`mnf <- brick(mnf_filename)`

Throws the following warning:

> This file has a rotation
>    Support for such files is limited and results of data processing might be wrong. Proceed with caution & consider using the "rectify" function

Running the rectify function
`mnf_r <- rectify(mnf)`

Throws the following error:

> Error in .intersectExtent(x, y, validate = TRUE) : 
>     Objects do not intersect
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In .local(x, ...) : min y larger than max y
>   2: In .local(x, ...) : min y larger than max y

And when rectifying just one layer in the raster stack like so,
`mnf_r <- rectify(subset(mnf, 1)`
generates the following error:

> Error in validityMethod(object) : invalid extent: ymin >= ymax

I can't tell what's wrong. Below is the output of 'extent(mnf)':

class       : Extent

xmin        : 720770.2

xmax        : 752353

ymin        : 4328909

ymax        : 4361487

Below is the output of `gdalinfo(mnf_filename)`:

[1] "Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF"
  [2] "Files: X:\gcwu\AVIRIS\f150429t01p00r07_refl_hpc18_v1_topo_American_MNF2.tif"
  [3] "Size is 701, 1821"
  [4] "Coordinate System is:"
  [5] "PROJCS[\"WGS 84 / UTM zone 10N\","
  [6] "    GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\","
  [7] "        DATUM[\"WGS_1984\","
  [8] "            SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,"
  [9] "                AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],"
 [10] "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],"
 [11] "        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,"
 [12] "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],"
 [13] "        UNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433,"
 [14] "            AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],"
 [15] "        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]],"
 [16] "    PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],"
 [17] "    PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],"
 [18] "    PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-123],"
 [19] "    PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],"
 [20] "    PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",500000],"
 [21] "    PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0],"
 [22] "    UNIT[\"metre\",1,"
 [23] "        AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],"
 [24] "    AXIS[\"Easting\",EAST],"
 [25] "    AXIS[\"Northing\",NORTH],"
 [26] "    AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"32610\"]]"
 [27] "GeoTransform ="
 [28] "  720770.204, 13.16436670051244, -12.27597040459283"
 [29] "  4352881.37, -12.27597040459283, -13.16436670051244"
 [30] "Metadata:"
 [31] "  AREA_OR_POINT=Area"
 [32] "  TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION=1"
 [33] "  TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION=1"
 [34] "Image Structure Metadata:"
 [35] "  INTERLEAVE=BAND"
 [36] "Corner Coordinates:"
 [37] "Upper Left  (  720770.204, 4352881.370) (120d26'23.54\"W, 39d17'49.87\"N)"
 [38] "Lower Left  (  698415.662, 4328909.058) (120d42'21.35\"W, 39d 5'12.32\"N)"
 [39] "Upper Right (  729998.425, 4344275.915) (120d20' 9.24\"W, 39d13' 2.37\"N)"
 [40] "Lower Right (  707643.883, 4320303.603) (120d36' 6.99\"W, 39d 0'25.66\"N)"
 [41] "Center      (  714207.043, 4336592.486) (120d31'15.89\"W, 39d 9' 7.89\"N)"